# Getting specific cell value from NetCDF file slow on first execution

Tags: raster, netcdf, python-xarray, data-cube

I am accessing a netcdf file using the xarray python library. The specific file that I am using is publicly [available](https://zenodo.org/record/4943354).

So, the file has several variables, and for most of these variables the dimensions are: time: 4314, x: 700, y: 562. I am using the ET_500m variable, but the behaviour is similar for the other variables as well. The chunking is: 288, 36, 44.

I am retrieving a single cell and printing the value using the following code:

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset('./dataset_greece.nc')
print(ds.ET_500m.values[0][0][0])
```

According to my understanding, xarray should locate directly the position of the chunk that contains the corresponding value in disk and read it. Since the size of the chunk should not be bigger than a couple of MBs, I would expect this to take a few seconds or even less. But instead, it takes more than 2 minutes.

If, in the same script, I retrieve the value of another cell, even if it is located in a different chunk (e.g. `print(ds.ET_500m.values[1000][500][500])`), then this second retrieval takes only some milliseconds.

So my question is what exactly causes this overhead in the first retrieval?

EDIT: I just saw that in xarray open_dataset there is the optional parameter cache, which according to the [manual](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_dataset.html):

> If True, cache data loaded from the underlying datastore in memory as NumPy arrays when accessed to avoid reading from the underlying data- store multiple times. Defaults to True [...]

So, when I set this to False, subsequent fetches are also slow like the first one. But my question remains. Why is this so slow since I am only accessing a single cell. I was expecting that xarray directly locates the chunk on disk and only reads a couple of MBs.

Comment: My guess is that this is down to xarray being lazy. When it gets the first chunk it will retrieve info that will make getting the second chunk easier. Have you tried getting the second chunk first?

Comment: It doesn't matter what position the first cell is at. The first fetch is always slow, whereas subsequent fetches are fast. After searching the laziness/caching hint I saw that this is mentioned in xarray documentation. Please see edit in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than selecting from the `.values` property, subset the array first:

```py
print(ds.ET_500m[0, 0, 0].values)
```

The problem is that [`.values`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.DataArray.values.html) coerces the data to a numpy array, so you're loading all of the data and then subsetting the array. There's no way around this for xarray - numpy doesn't have any concept of lazy loading, so as soon as you call `.values` xarray has no option but to load (or compute) all of your data.

If the data is a dask-backed array, you could use [`.data`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.data.html) rather than `.values` to access the dask array and use positional indexing on the dask array, e.g. `ds.ET_500m.data[0, 0, 0]`. But if the data is just a lazy-loaded netCDF `.data` will have the same load-everything pitfall described above.